# How to correctly use static variables in class methods?

Tags: php, class, variables, methods, static

I'm trying to do this code in PHP:

```
class T {

    public $y = 4;

    public function y() { return $this->y; }

    public function q()
    {
        static $j = $this->y;   
        echo $j;
    }
}

$r = new T();
$r->q();
```

and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in C:\xampp\htdocs\dermaquality\test.php on line 13
static $j = $this->y;
```

If I set the value manually, there is no problem, but if I set the value calling y() or $this->y I get that error.
I don't know why?

Comment: here you go: http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign values to static variables which are the result of expressions will cause a parse error.

```
static $int = 0;          // correct 
static $int = 1+2;        // wrong  (as it is an expression)
static $int = sqrt(121);  // wrong  (as it is an expression too)
```